# using php in html to show a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a table in a HTML Document using php, and here is my code:

```
<p>Below is the table of all the books available: <br />

<table border="1" ><th>Book ID</th><th>Subject</th><th>Title</th><th>Print Edition</th><th>Condition</th><th>Asking Price</th>


<?php 
    $server= 'MYSERVER';
    $user = 'MYUSERNAME';
    $password = 'MYPASSWORD';
    $database = 'MYDBNAME';
    $mysqli = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    foreach ( $mysqli->query('SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user') as $row ) 
    {?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $res['ID'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['Subject'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['Title'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['PrintEdition'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['Cond'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['Price'];?></td></tr>
<?php } 
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
</table>

<br />
If you like to request any of these titles, Do the following:
```

.
.
.
.

However, it seems I'm not sure what is happening, but I am having this as the outcome on my Chrome (this is the actual screen shot of my webpage):

---

Below is the table of all the books available: 
query('SELECT * FROM entry_database') as $row ) {?>
    Book ID Subject Title   Print Edition   Condition   Asking Price

(The above row looks like a table)

```
If you like to request any of these titles, Do the following:
```

---

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I have a hunch that it is because HTML treats the -> as a tag. Is there any way of fixing this?

Just to explain, I have looked at all the answers, tried all the answers, and as far as I am aware, I can't find the answer.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1:

So I managed to sort out the additional code showing, thanks to @Fred -ii-

However, the data is not showing. I tried the following to output the date, but no success:

```
foreach ( $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM entry_database') as $row ) 
    {?>
    <?php echo $row['ID'];?><br /><?php echo $row['Subject'];?><br /><?php echo $row['Title'];?><br /><?php echo $row['PrintEdition'];?><br /><?php echo $row['Cond'];?><br /><?php echo $row['Price'];?><br />
<?php } 
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

We are getting there, I am sure

Comment: Add `$` to `('server', 'user', 'password', 'database')` and make sure your file is `.php` which is why your page comes out looking that way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Shouldn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Jonast92 I should but I'm just afraid that it will lead to more questions like "my data isn't showing from DB...". I know the drill all too well ;)

Comment: @Jonast92 Ok, I did post it as answer. I'll just wait for the OP to come back. I even spotted another error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'll make this an answer:

Add `$` to `('server', 'user', 'password', 'database')` which should read as
`($server, $user, $password, $database)` otherwise PHP will throw you a message about "Undefined constants...".

You need to make sure your file is `.php` which is why your page comes out looking that way, *as code* instead of being properly parsed.

You can instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, but that's just more work.

This I am highly suspecting is what you're doing, trying to run an `.html` file and expect it to run it as PHP just as a web browser would for HTML files.

- If you're attempting to run this on your own computer, you will need to install a Webserver.

Plus, you're doing `as $row` and echoing `echo $res` that should be `as $res`

You're also only selecting the "user" and "host" columns from `SELECT user,host` and wanting to echo `ID` and `Subject` and `Title` and `PrintEdition` and `Cond` and `Price` which won't work.

You need to either add/select all those columns, or do `SELECT *` and make absolutely sure that those columns do in fact exist in your table.

---

**Edit:**

Replace this block:

```
foreach ( $mysqli->query('SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user') as $row ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Subject'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['PrintEdition'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Cond'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Price'];?></td>
    </tr>
```

with:

```
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM entry_database');

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Subject'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['PrintEdition'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Cond'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Price'];?></td>
    </tr>
```

---

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th align="left" valign="middle">ID</th>
            <th align="center" valign="middle">Subject</th>
            <th align="center" valign="middle">Title</th> 

            <th align="left" valign="middle">PrintEdition</th>
            <th align="center" valign="middle">Cond</th>
            <th align="center" valign="middle">Price</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $server= 'MYSERVER';
    $user = 'MYUSERNAME';
    $password = 'MYPASSWORD';
    $database = 'MYDBNAME';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
    $results = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM entry_database');
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['PrintEdition']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['Cond']; ?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['Price']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your points and help. I have changed the server to $server etc, I've also changed the scope of sql query to include everything. How do you want me to change the file to php? shall I just change the extension? I'm running it on a server, but I'm editing the page and the files with Dreamweaver.  Again, thanks for all the help and apologies for my noobishness.

Comment: @Sep You're welcome. Yes, you will need to change the extension of your file(s) to `.php` in order for them to parse properly.

Comment: FANTASTIC. Thank you very much @Fred. So the table is updating, but now the problem is that the data isn't showing. I tried to just output the data, but still nothing. I have added an update with the code for checking the date

Comment: @Sep Reload my answer and look for **Edit** near the bottom. Also make sure your column names are correct. "Title" is not the same as "title" etc.

Comment: Fred YOU ARE A STAR!!! It worked.. I have to say, I was so stupid. The reason that it was showing blank was because I had previously flushed my database, and hadn't added any data!!! DUH!! Thanks alot. I can't mark the answer as done, so if you can, close the question, or to the admin of this website, please vote up for this answer.

Comment: @Sep You're very much welcome, and I'm glad everything worked out for the better. P.s.: Thanks, you're too kind, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'password', 'database');
```

should be

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
```

Comment: I would assume that the user hard codes them but changed them before posting so as not to expose sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you're using $row as the loop variable, but then inside the loop you're referring to $res.
Also, you need to execute the query in mysqli then bind the result, then do the loop.
Refer to example in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1812

Answer (score 0):

your code has to be like this:

```
<p>Below is the table of all the books available: <br />

<table border="1" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book ID</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Print Edition</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
            <th>Asking Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

<?php
$server= 'MYSERVER';
$user = 'MYUSERNAME';
$password = 'MYPASSWORD';
$database = 'MYDBNAME';
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
foreach ( $mysqli->query('SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user') as $row ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Subject'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['PrintEdition'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Cond'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Price'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
} 
?>

<br />
If you like to request any of these titles, Do the following:
```

in the foreach you defined the values in a variable $row
then you used the values $res, that's not gonna work
also the mysqli connection was wrong defined.

I tested the code and this code is working for me ;)